# Is there any need to assign null pointer to std::auto_ptr

Tags: c++

Previous, I have the following code.

```
double* a[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Initialize.
    a[i] = 0;
}
```

The purpose of initialize array of `a` to 0 is that, when I iterative delete element of `a`, everything will work fine still even there are no memory allocated still for element of `a`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Fine.
    delete a[i];
}
```

Now, I would like to take advantage of auto_ptr, to avoid having manual call to delete.

```
std::auto_ptr<double> a[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Initialize. Is there any need for me to do so still?
    a[i] = std::auto_ptr<double>(0);
}
```

I was wondering, whether there is any need for me to initialize `auto_ptr` to hold a null pointer? My feeling is no. I just want to confirm on this, so that there aren't any catch behind.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you think you want an array of pointers to double in the first place. Changing that to a array of `auto_ptr<double>` sounds to me like it's missing the real problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++03 specifies the constructor of auto_ptr as follows:

```
explicit auto_ptr(X* p =0) throw();             // Note the default argument

Postconditions: *this holds the pointer p.
```

This means that the below is perfectly well-formed. There is no need to initialize

```
auto_ptr<int> a = auto_ptr<int>();
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::auto_ptr`'s default constructor does the NULL-assignment for you -- or, as the standard (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) puts it, the constructor is declared as:

explicit           auto_ptr(X* p =0) throw();

(`X` being the template parameter class, i.e., this is for `std::auto_ptr<X>`).

Answer (score 2):

You can zero initialize all members of an array using:

```
double* a[100] = {0}; // is equivalent
```

An alternative to deletion by using `for_each`:

```
struct delete_object
{
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T *ptr){ delete ptr;}
};

//later in the code...
std::for_each( &a[ 0 ], &a[ 0 ] + sizeof a / sizeof a[ 0 ], delete_object());
```

Now for your question:

> whether there is any need for me to initialize auto_ptr to hold a null pointer?

There is no need to initialize the `auto_ptr`s array. The members will be default initialized if you leave it out.

However, note that `auto_ptr` may not be usable for its move semantics (copy of ownership) if you need to pass around the pointers to other functions. Also, in the coming standard `auto_ptr` is likely to be deprecated. Try using something like `std::tr1::unique_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` (the latter is a reference counted smart pointer).