# Should I explicitly zero initialize auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

Some of my colleagues prefer to explicitly initialize `std::auto_ptr` to `0` in constructor initialization list, but it will be initialized to `0` in it's constructor without any explicit initialization. So is there any reason to do it?

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
  A() : SomePtr(0)
  {
  }

private:
  std::auto_ptr<SomeType> SomePtr;
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any need to assign null pointer to std::auto_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664145/is-there-any-need-to-assign-null-pointer-to-stdauto-ptr)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the default constructor of `std::auto_ptr` does exactly that, so doing it explicitly is not necessary. In any case, it's a matter of style and you should be consistent. For instance, would you explicitly call the default constructor of a member vector in the constructor initialization list?

As a side note, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in the upcoming standard

Comment: The "upcoming" standard has happened, it's now the "latest" standard! Hoorah, and cheering! Granted, it hasn't been *implemented* yet.

Comment: Ok, the only reason is style and consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Psychology.

For built-in types, you probably already *know* they are uninitialized unless you do so explicitly.  For classes, this is not the case.

A strive to consistency results in explicit initialization everywhere.  This allows you to forget if `A::SomePtr` is a built-in or a class type.  Pretty useless, imho, since the amount of built-in types is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

One reason maybe clarity, but that should be the only one. I myself prefer not to write unneccessary intialization, especially if that completely spares me from writing a default constructor for the surrounding class and just let the compiler do its job. Whereas it's merely a matter of style, I think too much over-paranoia does even harm the clarity of the code.